# How to get data from a url encoded string that is in an external source

Tags: php

I am making an ecommerce platform. The service i use ([paynow.co.zw](https://www.paynow.co.zw/)) to push ussd payment request to users sends a payment status update in a url encoded string to a webpage hosted by them. The service provides me with a url to that page where i am to check the status of the payment among other data. An example of such a page is [here](https://www.paynow.co.zw/Interface/CheckPayment/?guid=0cd3eb23-9605-4337-9a1a-2a8cdfc4f0d1). I would like to do something like  `if  (status == 'paid'){ //update notification page}` later on.

I have tried all i can to even atleast display contents of the link. The [developer hub](https://developers.paynow.co.zw/docs/polling_status.html) of the paynow service does not help much on how to go about. I have searched paynow developer forums but i found no help.

If it can not be done i would like to atleast `var_dump($Url)`, convert it to string then search that string for the word "paid", "pending" or "cancelled".

Here is some of what i tried:

```
<?php
      $str = file("https://www.paynow.co.zw/Interface/CheckPayment/?guid=0cd3eb23-9605-4337-9a1a-2a8cdfc4f0d1")
  //$str = "reference=Invoice+35&paynowreference=9401889&amount=52.90&status=Paid";
   parse_str($str, $output);
   
   if ($output['status'] == 'Paid'){
       echo "Payment complete";
       }else{
        echo "Payment Pending";
      }
 ?>
```

Comment: `paid` and `Paid` are different things.

Comment: And you should probably rather use `file_get_contents` than `file` here.

Comment: `if ($output['status]' == 'paid'){` <-- quotes are placed wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can try it, using `explode` you can do it easily. Use `isset` while accessing array value to overcome any index error

```
$str = file("https://www.paynow.co.zw/Interface/CheckPayment/?guid=0cd3eb23-9605-4337-9a1a-2a8cdfc4f0d1"); 
$data = explode("&",$str[0]);

$out_put = explode("=",$data[3]);

if(strtolower($out_put[1]) == "paid"){
    echo "Payment complete";
}else{
    echo "Payment Pending";
}
```